# Cygwin SSHD causes 100% CPU load

Tags: windows, cygwin, openssh, sshd

I run cygwin 32-bit on Windows 10 Pro b19042 [`Cygwin is 3.2.0-1`], with OpenSSH [`8.5p1-1`], using `sshd` to access the machine from afar, and notice (often multiple) processes of `sshd.exe` with 100% CPU load.

- A call stack shown with `procexp` shows function names like `cygwin1.dll!acl_get_perm` and `cygwin1.dll!_assert`
- I have updated to the latest cygwin multiple times and reboots don't help either

Can anyone give me some advice on how to proceed further?

Comment: If there is a 64-bit cygwin, why not use that?

Comment: If needing OpenSSH, why not just use the Microsoft port of OpenSSH ([Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH))?

Comment: Have you tested latest snapshot ? https://cygwin.com/snapshots/

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille: It's a 32-bit system.

Comment: @JW0914: The MS port doesn't have a bash, which really makes things much more awkward.

Comment: @matzeri: I haven't. But that's a good idea. Right now the problem didn't reappear, so I cannot test you proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

A downgrade to an earlier version of SSHD fixed the problem.